# Gute Anrede für Bedienungen

Tags: politeness, salutation, political-correctness

Ich suche eine gute Anrede für Bedienungen im Restaurant. Seit *Fräulein* in Verruf gebracht wurde, denke ich oft über eine Alternative nach. Ich habe bereits etliche Bedienungen gefragt und oft fanden sie *Fräulein* diskriminierend. Diese Untergruppe lehnte aber auch *junge Frau* und *Madame* ausnahmslos ab. Ich denke jetzt über *Frau Kellnerin* nach.

Bisher sehe ich die einzigen Ausweichmöglichkeiten in *Entschuldigung* und *Verzeihung,* wozu ich auch ständig greife. Aber das alles klingt nicht  souverän, wenn man es coram publico mehr als einmal rufen muss. Es eignet sich für den Fall, in dem schon Blickkontakt besteht.

Ich habe auch *Bedienung* erwogen, welches ich selbst sehr herablassend finde.

Besonders störend finde ich, dass diejenigen, welche *Fräulein* in Verruf brachten, sich nicht um einen vollwertigen Ersatzbegriff kümmerten. Solche positiven Entwicklungen kann man ja sonst wohl beobachten etwa bei der Wortgruppe *Krüppel/Schwerbeschädigte/Schwerbehinderte.* Dies kann meines Erachtens nur daran liegen, dass die Betreffenden sich durchaus gegen ältere Damen abgrenzen wollen. Sonst hätte sich wohl *Madame* etabliert. Das Thema ärgert mich so, dass ich auch an seltenen Vorschlägen und Wortschöpfungen interessiert bin!

Es ist mir erstmal relativ egal, ob die Bedienung den Ausdruck regional, lustig oder veraltet findet und was sie – wenn ich es nicht höre – erzählt. Das wäre der zweite oder dritte Schritt. Wichtig ist mir, dass ich die Formel meistens einsetzen kann und dass darauf reagiert wird, aber ohne dass Sexismus-Vorwürfe und ähnliche Kritik aufkommen. So habe ich es schon mehrmals erlebt, dass warten, auf Blickkontakt hoffen, Handzeichen und *Verzeihung* nichts bewirken, *Fräulein* aber **sofort** eine (wütende) Bedienung heraufbeschwört. Ich wünsche mir eine ähnliche Wirkung, aber ohne die angeblich politisch inkorrekte Komponente.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45103/discussion-on-question-by-ludi-gute-anrede-fur-bedienungen).

Answer (score 26):

Meine Antwort basiert lediglich auf meiner langjährigen (und andauernden) Gastrotätigkeit.
In einem ganz normalen Restaurant, einem Café oder einer Bar gibt es:

**nichts**

Alles klingt gestelzt, steif, herablassend oder unnatürlich und würde vom Kellner oder der Kellnerin direkt den anderen im Team als Anekdote weitererzählt. **Kurz die Hand heben** oder einfach **„Entschuldigung“** sind die gängigen Formen. Auch ist ein etwas lauter gesagtes „Entschuldigung“ verbunden mit Gestik relativ klar an das Service-Personal gerichtet. Verwirrung halte ich für wenig wahrscheinlich. Entsteht ja auch in der U-Bahn eher selten, wenn man „Entschuldigung“ sagt, weil man wo vorbeimöchte.

In der gehobenen Reiche-Leute-Gastro (im Adlon oder so) mag das anders sein, ist aber mit Sicherheit auch stark regional geprägt. „Ober“ in Berlin ist ziemlich unvorstellbar heutzutage (wirkt wie ein Witz).

Comment: Der »Ober« ist in Wien die beste Wahl wenn man einen männlichen Kellner herbeirufen will, nicht nur in der gehobenen Gastronomie, sondern auch im billigen Studentenbeisl. Beim weiblichen Servierpersonal gibt es aber auch nichts besseres als »Hallo« und »’tschuldig’n«.

Comment: Ich habe hier in Kreuzberg beim Frühstück auch einmal gehört, wie eine ältere Dame den bedienenden jungen Mann mit „Herr Ober“ anredete. Darauf antwortete dieser, das hätte er ja schon lange nicht mehr gehört, nur um sich dann zu korrigieren, dass er das eigentlich noch nie gehört hätte.

Comment: Na, in Kreuzberg ist eh überall Selbstbedienung und Pfand soll man auch noch zahlen. ;) Dennoch wird natürlich Trinkgeld erwartet. Einfach mal mit "Genossin!" probieren. ;)

Answer (score 17):

In ihren „Richtlinien zur Vermeidung sexistischen Sprachgebrauchs“ von 1980 empfehlen Guentherodt, Pusch, Trömel-Plötz und Hellinger, die wegbereitend für den sprachlichen Feminismus im deutschsprachigen Raum waren und somit großen Anteil am (berechtigten) Aussterben von *Fräulein* haben, als Alternativen für ebendiese Anrede im Restaurant Folgendes:

- *Bitte!*
- *Entschuldigen Sie!*
- *Würden Sie uns die Karte bringen, bitte?*

(PS: Ich habe zwischenzeitlich Luise Pusch gefragt, ob sie heute eine andere oder bessere Empfehlung hätte. Sie hat das verneint, erkennt aber das Problem an. Als durchaus gebräuchliche Varianten nannte sie: *Hallo!*, *Ich möchte gern zahlen!* und *Frau Kellnerin!*)

In einem Kommentar hatte ich in diesem Sinne bereits für einige häufige Situationen die typisch knappen **Appelle** *Die Karte, bitte! Die Rechnung, bitte! Zahlen, bitte!* genannt, die natürlich auch etwas wortreicher ausfallen können, z. B. *Wir würden gerne zahlen!*

Das ist aber alles kein direkter Ersatz für eine **anonyme Anrede** im Dienstleistungskontext. Als gesellschaftliche statt sprachliche Lösung würde sich anbieten, dass sich das zuständige Personal (wie in manchen anderen Ländern und Branchen schon lange üblich) bei der Begrüßung den Gästen mit eindeutigem **Rufnamen** (ggf. ein Pseudonym) vorstellt oder, sofern sich das namentliche Herbeirufen eingebürgert hat, wenigstens ein deutlich lesbares Namensschild trägt. Personal, das „man“ bis vor 30 Jahren *Fräulein* oder *Junge* genannt hätte, würde dann tendenziell beim Vornamen, alle anderen mit vorangestelltem *Frau* oder *Herr* beim Nachnamen gerufen werden.

Der einzige existierende **direkte Ersatz**, der mir neben *Herr/Frau Ober(kellner(in))* einfällt, wäre *Bedienung!*, was allerdings sehr leicht barsch und herablassend klingt – und so nur in bestimmten Situation angebracht wäre. 
Eher scherzhaft habe ich auch schon *<del>Gaston</del>Garçon!* gehört, aber nicht darauf geachtet, ob damit auch Frauen angesprochen wurden – selbst würde ich es nicht verwenden, ebenso wenig *Herr Wirt* und *Frau Wirtin*. Bei manchen speziellen Funktionen mag das anders sein, z. B. *Sommelier!* oder *Barkeeper!*

Analog zum ebenfalls weitgehend ausgestorbenen *Zimmermädchen*, das nun als *Zimmerservice* anklopft, hätte sich das zu billigen Wortspielen einladende **Tischservice* oder **Speiseservice* bzw. **Getränkeservice* etablieren können, hat es aber (bisher) nicht getan, selbst *Service, bitte!* ist (in diesem Kontext) völlig unüblich.

Nicht zu vergessen ist im Übrigen gerade in mit fremden Personen gefüllten Räumlichkeiten die **nonverbale Kommunikation** nach erfolgreich aufgenommenem Blickkontakt mit Gesten (Zunicken, Winken; Fingerreiben, Trinkgebärde, Deuten/Zeigen, Anzahl per ausgestreckten Fingern) und Objekten (leeres Glas, Geldbörse/Kreditkarte, …). Alles was para- oder nonverbale Töne erzeugt, also bspw. Schnipsen, Schnalzen, Klatschen und Pfeifen, ist hingegen weitgehend verpönt, nur Räuspern ist meist okay.

Comment: ＋１  »Bitte!« statt »Entschuldigung?«… das muss ich unbedingt mal ausprobieren.

Comment: Sobald Blickkontakt besteht ist es kein Problem, den Finger zu heben. Problematisch ist es, etwas Aufmerksamkeitserregendes zu performen, ohne die anderen Gäste zu stören, mit offenem Addressaten, weil etwa ein Mann u. eine Frau als mögliche Kandidaten herumwuseln. "Würden Sie uns ..." kann man eigentlich nur äußern, wenn man schon Blickkontakt hat. Evtl. steht die Telefonnummer auf der Karte die schon am Tisch liegt, und man kann anrufen. :) Die Vase runterschmeißen, "Oh, Pardon!" rufend hat sich bewährt. ;)

Comment: Richten Sie Frau Pusch bei Gelegenheit aus, daß man mit *Bitte!* noch schlechter fährt als mit *Verzeihung*,und daß sie, die uns dies einbrockte, am ehesten einen Gegenvorschlag unterbreiten könnte, der eine Chance hätte, sich durchzusetzen. Mir liegt wenig daran *Fräulein* zu rehabilitieren – das Kind ist schon vor zu langer Zeit in den Brunnen gefallen – aber einen Ersatz möchte ich doch finden, bevor ich den Löffel abgebe!

Answer (score 17):

Wenn die Gaststätte nicht zu vornehm ist, habe ich mit **Chefin** bisher gute Erfahrungen gemacht.

Insbesondere dann, wenn die Bedienung eindeutig *nicht* die Chefin ist...

Comment: Ich habe vorgestern die ersten (guten) Erfahrungen damit gesammelt. Die (viel jüngere) Bedienung grinste mich an und kam sofort:)

Comment: Dies ist der einzige praktische Vorschlag mit (situativ eingeschränktem) erwiesenem Nutzen, daher meine Belohnung!

Comment: @Ludi: cool! Dankeschön.

Comment: Ich würde mich doch aber um Höflichkeit bemühen und *Frau Chefin* sagen.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann unnötig. Die Situation ist ironisch genug, da würde das nur gestelzt und abseitig wirken... Man sagt ja auch nicht **Herr Chef**. Da gibt's kein Herr/Frau davor!

Comment: @eckes  Prinzipiell hast du natürlich recht, aber jetzt stell dir eine laute Gastwirtschaft vor. Wenn du da nur *Chefin* rufst, geht das leicht unter. Wenn du *Frau Chefin* rufst, hast du eine Silbe mehr akustische Präsenz und vor der *Chefin* auch noch einen kurzen Alarmruf.