# Interjektionale Anrede für Unbekannte

Tags: word-choice

Situation: Eine mir unbekannte Person sitzt im Zug neben mir. Beim Verlassen ihres Sitzplatzes vergisst sie einen Regenschirm, was mir auffällt, als die Person schon einige Schritte entfernt ist. Welche Anrede rufe ich (höflich) hinter ihr her, um sie darauf aufmerksam zu machen?

Man kann natürlich »Hey Sie!« oder »Entschuldigung!« oder »Stop!« rufen, aber eine echte Anrede (und höflich) ist das ja nicht. Ich behelfe mir typischerweise mit »Monsieur!« bzw. »Madame!«. Aber gibt es nicht auch gute Alternativen im Deutschen?

In eine ähnliche Richtung geht diese Frage: [Gute Anrede für Bedienungen](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24397/ich-suche-eine-gute-anrede-f%C3%BCr-bedienungen/24537#24537). Tenor der Antworten: am besten Verzicht auf Anrede. Gilt das auch im obigen (weniger speziellen) Kontext? Also dann etwa: »Warten Sie!«?

Comment: Sowohl hier als auch in der verlinkten Frage wundere ich mich, was ihr gegen "Entschuldigung" habt. Ist doch super. Eine allg. Anrede ist relativ schwer zu finden. Nehmen wir mal an, wir würden uns auf "Dame" bzw. "Herr" (also die Pendants zu Madame und Monsieur) einigen, was sagst du dann, wenn die Person ein Kind ist? Ich denke bei Personen (einschließlich Kinder) bis ~30 kann man "junge Dame", "junger Herr" sagen (die Kids würden sich da immerhin geschmeichelt fühlen), aber bei älteren "die Dame", "der Herr" zu sagen, klingt doch sehr gehoben. Nur "Dame" bzw "Herr" ist zu plump.

Comment: Hm. Komisch, nicht wahr? "Dame" bzw. "Herr" solo zur Anrede geht überhaupt nicht. Während "meine Dame" oder "mein Herr" ein wenig besitzergreifend klingt. "Die Dame" und "der Herr". Ja, das ginge, würde ich tendenziell aber eher nachstellen, als als Eröffnung benutzen, also: "Sie haben Ihren Schirm vergessen, der Herr!"

Comment: @Em1 dann erinnere ich Sie nochmals daran: Entschuldigung ist unangenehm wenn es mehrmals wiederholt wird und alle Welt dreht sich um, nur nicht der Angesprochene!

Answer (score 9):

Mit Höflichkeit liegt man bei Fremden selten falsch. Obwohl vorbehaltloses Entschuldigen fraglich ist, bleibt es eine gute Alternative:

> **»Entschuldigen Sie, Sie haben Ihren Schirm vergessen!«**

Seit „Fräulein“ negativ konnotiert ist, muss man sich – vor allem Männer – bei der Bedienung pausenlos entschuldigen („… äh, Entschuldigung‽“); dies aber lieber einmal zuviel als zu wenig.

Das „Warten!!“ ist sicherlich auch okay, wenn Du es nicht mit zu vielen Ausrufungszeichen versiehst:

> **»Warten Sie, Ihr Schirm… bitte sehr!«** *(mit Lächeln)*

Als zwischengerufene Anrede finde ich „Entschuldigung“ für Fremde ziemlich angemessen. Ist ja nix anderes mit *Excusez-moi, monsieur* oder *Excuse me, madam*.

Bei jungen Menschen ist auch ein freundlich-vielsagendes „Ey!“ – dann als eigentliche Interjektion – in Ordnung, es dient dann zum aufmerksam machen. Dagegen ist „mein Herr“ eher veraltend, sodass es beim alternativlosen „Entschuldigung“ bleibt (oder auch beim **„Pardon!“** oder **„Verzeihung?“**).

Comment: +1 für die Fraglichkeit der vorbehaltlosen Entschuldigung. Wobei die zumindest bei der Bedienung noch eine halbe Berechtigung hat, da man üblicherweise ein Anliegen damit verbindet.

Comment: Och, naja, im Fall der o. g. Frage könnte man ja sagen *„Entschuldigung, dass ich Sie störe“* oder auch *„Entschuldigung, wir kennen uns nicht, aber…“* – natürlich sollte das nicht zur Folge haben, dass die Bedeutung einer ent-Schuld-igung abhanden gerät.

Comment: Selbstverständlich ist das möglich. Und sicherlich auch angebracht, wenn man bspw. jemanden bei irgendeiner Tätigkeit unterbricht, weil man selbst ein Anliegen hat. In der geschilderten Situation aber will ich nicht erst um Entschuldigung (oder meinetwegen Verzeihung) dafür bitten, bevor ich jemandem einen Gefallen tue.

Comment: Es ist eine Bitte um Entschuldigung dafür, dass man einen fremden menschen stört und anspricht.