# Die geschlechter(un)gerechte »Gattin«?

Tags: word-usage, politeness, political-correctness, gender-neutrality

In der Süddeutschen Zeitung vom 23. November steht in der Rubrik *aktuelles Lexikon* unter dem Titel *Gender-Star:*

> […] Die Ansätze zu einer geschlechtergerechten Sprache stammen aus den 70er-Jahren. Sie haben Wörtern wie »Fräulein« oder »Gattin« ein faktisches Ende bereitet. […]

Über das Fräulein wurde bereits [ausführlich](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/966/15318) [diskutiert](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/24397/15318). Verwundert hat mich allerdings, dass auch die »Gattin« ein Opfer der geschlechtergerechten Sprache sein soll. Nach meinem Sprachgefühl ist es ein völlig neutraler Begriff, der zwar nicht von jedermann verwendet wird, aber doch in keiner Weise die Gemeinte herabwürdigt oder sonstwie diskriminiert – schließlich ergibt sich das Wort meist durch einen deutlich sichtbaren Ring am Finger. Zusätzlich existiert die perfekte männliche Entsprechung im Wort »Gatte«, was man vom »Männlein« als Gegenstück zum »Fräulein« nicht behaupten kann. Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Gattin) bestätigt mich in meinen Gedanken und klassifiziert das Wort nur als »gehoben«, nicht als »veraltet« – im Gegenteil, es steht dort:

> Die Bezeichnung […] drückt besondere Höflichkeit aus.

Gibt es Kritik am Wort »Gattin« von feministischer oder »genderistischer« Seite?
Oder ist die Süddeutsche hier schlicht im Unrecht?

Comment: Hm, vielleicht bezieht sich die SZ auf Verwendungen wie „Bankier Dr. Müller und Gattin“?

Comment: Der Begriff ist wohl einfach als veraltet am absterben, genau wie Fräulein, denn die meisten Menschen scheren sich einen Teufel um Pusch und Trömmel-Plötz und folgen auch sonst keiner der Sprachinnovationen. Gattin ist m.W. kein Kritikpunkt gewesen.

Comment: @userunknown Dagegen spricht, dass beim Duden *Gattin* eben *nicht* als veraltet klassifiziert ist.

Comment: @Jan: Leider ist der Duden selbst als veraltet am absterben. ;) Wahrscheinlich gibt es noch einen regen Gebrauch in bestimmten Milieus (Sparkassendirektoren, Dressurreiten) die mir fremd sind.

Comment: @chirlu Das dürfte der Grund sein, der entfernt in der SZ-Redaktion missverstanden oder im Artikel schlecht wiedergegeben wurde. Dein Kommentar sollte daher eine Antwort sein. Diese nicht parallele Behandlung, die natürlich auch mit _Frau_ und _Ehefrau_ (oder _Gatte, Mann, Ehemann_) etc. funktioniert, wurde tatsächlich erfolgreich kritisiert, ebenso _Familie Hans Müller_, weil sie Frauen als bloße, niedergestellte Anhängsel eines Mannes darstellt. Es gibt natürlich trotzdem Fälle, in denen das „plus one“ eines eingeladenen Gastes namentlich nicht bekannt ist.

Comment: PS: Ich glaube mich jetzt doch zu erinnern, mindestens einmal in einem sprachkritischen feministischen Text aus den frühen Achtzigern _Gattin_ (und _Gatte_!) kritisiert gesehen zu haben, weil sie mit _begatten_ in Verbindung gebracht wurden und daher die Ehe auf den Zeugungsakt beschränken würden – oder so ähnlich.

Comment: @Crissov Uuuuh, wenn du *den* ausgraben kannst, ist das wahrscheinlich die Antwort die ich suche (und noch ein Grund mehr für mich, mich über den Feminismus aufzuregen) =D

Comment: @Jan Habe es in meinen elektronischen Aufzeichnungen und auch bei einer kurzen Onlinerecherche leider nicht gefunden.

Comment: Der Vorwurf entspringt der mangelnden Bildung der verantwortlichen (weil sprachliche Zusammenhänge umgekehrt wurden, *Gatte* kommt von ahd gigat, *passend*) und ihrem fehlgeleiteten Ehrgeiz. Auch heute erzwingen solche Pseudofeministinnen, daß ein Buch Chemie für Pharmazeutinnen genannt wird, versäumen es aber, den Schutz vor Kinderehen zu unterstützen! Sicher drehen sich die wahren Feministinnen von einst im Grabe!

Comment: @Jan die Behauptung, wenn auch nicht die Originalquellen, finden Sie hier. https://www.sekada.de/korrespondenz/anrede-und-anschriften/artikel/gattin-und-gatte-warum-sie-auf-diese-formulierungen-besser-verzichten-sollten/  Den Beweis für deren Unverschämtheit finden Sie hier unter *Etymologie* https://www.dwds.de/wb/Gatte#et-1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wie bereits vermutet, bezieht sich die Kritik tatsächlich auf "Herr X und Gattin":

http://www.frauenbeauftragte.uni-muenchen.de/genderkompetenz/sprache/sprache_pdf.pdf

Relativ unbegründet, da man es umgekehrt auch so macht - Petra und ihr Mann/Freund/Lebensabgschnittsgefährte/Freundin etc. pp.

Die Darstellung der SZ ist sachlich falsch, denn dann müsste man konsequent jede weibliche Ableitung eines Partners schmähen.