# Höflicher Begriff für eine junge Frau

Tags: word-choice, politeness, political-correctness

Gibt es im Deutschen ein Wort, das eine **junge Frau** des Alters zwischen ungefähr 16 und 25 Jahren bezeichnet?
*Mädchen* wird ja eher für Kinder benutzt, *Fräulein* ist veraltet und *Mädel* ist eher regional und ist in meiner Vorstellung etwas unhöflich gegenüber jungen Frauen des o.g. Alters.

Hier zwei Beispiele, für die Verwendung des Wortes:

1. Wenn ich z.B. meinem Opa erzählen würde, dass es eine junge Frau
   gibt, die mir gefällt und es würde sich um eine junge Frau handeln,
   die z.B. 23 ist, welches Wort würde ich hier am besten nehmen?
2. Wenn ich auf der Straße einer unbekannten jungen Frau hinterherrufen
   würde, damit sie stehen bleibt und auf mich wartet, wie würde ich
   sie in diesem Fall am besten ansprechen? Was würde ich in diesem
       Fall rufen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to refer to a woman based on her age?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/26639/how-to-refer-to-a-woman-based-on-her-age)

Comment: related: [Gute Anrede für Bedienungen](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/24397)

Comment: **Bitte um erneute Beachtung:** https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/807/what-to-do-when-the-asker-cannot-understand-the-duplicate-question-due-to-it-bei und https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14/if-the-same-question-is-asked-in-german-and-english-is-it-a-duplicate - es gibt einen Mehrheitsbeschluss, dass Fragen in Englisch **kein** Duplikat einer auf Deutsch gestellten Frage sein sollen. Wer diesen Beschluss aufheben möchte sei an [Meta] verwiesen.

Answer (score 8):

Ich sehe überhaupt kein Problem, dem Opa zu sagen

> Du, Opa, ich habe da ein nettes Mädchen kennengelernt.

("Mädchen" kann man in diesem Kontext in Grenzen für Frauen bis Ende 20 verwenden.)

In der direkten Ansprache passt „Mädchen“ natürlich nicht so richtig – einer jungen Frau auf der Straße „He, Mädchen“ hinterherzurufen, kommt eher nicht so gut. Hier passt eher eine geschlechtsunspezifische Anrede, oder sowas wie

> Hallo, junge Frau, ich glaube, Sie haben da was verloren.

Answer (score 5):

Mit den später der Frage hinzugefügten konkreten Anwendungsbeispielen wird die Frage besser beantwortbar.

#### 1) Junger Mann zum Opa

> "Opa, du, ich hab' da **eine** kennengelernt, mannomann, die hat's vielleicht in sich! Ich bring' sie nächste Woche mal mit, dann siehst du."

Das Prinzip hier ist, *überhaupt keine* Bezeichnung zu wählen. Trotzdem füllt der Gesprächspartner die Lücke richtig aus. Wenn man Linguist ist, könne man auch von einem "Null-Lexem" sprechen.

#### 2) Einer Frau hinterherufen, damit sie stehenbleibt

Das ist natürlich per so schon scharf an der Grenze der Unhöflichkeit, da hilft die Wortwahl nicht mehr viel. "He, Sie!" geht auf keinen Fall. "He, Du" würde schon eher gehen. Aber du suchtest ja ein Substantiv. Nun, auch das ist schwierig. Wenn du rufst:

> Hallo, junge Frau!

dann klingt es etwas onkelhaft. Du willst für sie aber kein Onkel sein, sondern - vermute ich mal - ein potentieller Paarungspartner, es kommt dir also darauf an, dass sie dich einerseits als gleichwertig (ihrer Gruppe zugehörig) erkennt, gleichzeitig dich aber auch noch toll findet. Es gibt eine Menge Ausdrücke wie "Hey, Süße!", aber höflich und kultiviert sind sie logischerweise alle nicht, denn höflich und kultiviert wäre es ja gerade, der Schnecke *nicht* hinterherzurufen.

Der praktische Ausweg ist, sie nicht direkt mit einer Bezeichnung (junge Frau, Süße, Gnä Frau) anzusprechen, sondern auf irgendeinem Umweg über ein Sachthema. "Verzeihung, könnten Sie [oder: könntest Du] mir sagen, wo ich hier einen Drogeriemarkt finde" wäre höflich genug (ist aber auch reichlich dröge).

Aber hier sind wir nun schon lange weg von Fragen des deutschen Wortschatzes; vielmehr sprechen wir hier über die in einer Kultur praktizierten und akzeptierten Anbahnungstechniken zwischen Mann und Frau. Ich glaube, dafür gibt es ein eigenes Forum...

Du kannst natürlich rufen:

> Djevuschka! Warten Sie mal!

Vielleicht kann sie ein bisschen Russisch und findet es interessant, so angesprochen zu werden. Jedenfalls klingt es exotisch, und das ist für deinen Zweck ja oft ein Vorteil.

Oder wie wäre es mit einem klassischen

> Mademoiselle! Warten Sie mal!

Das ist immerhin ein erkennbar kultiviertes Wort für eine junge Frau oder Dame. Das Wort ist zwar völlig aus der Mode seit etwa 150 Jahren. Aber Moden können ja wiederkehren...

Comment: _"Hallo, junge Frau!"_ mach das mal mit einer Service Mitarbeiterin in einem Restaurant. Es wird höchstwahrscheinlich nicht gut funktionieren.

Comment: Zu sexistisch Alles! Ganz objektiv! Komm' mir bitte nicht mit "Gender-Wahn" jetzt! Es ist ganz offensichtlich!

Comment: _"Ich glaube, dafür gibt es ein eigenes Forum..."_ Stack Exchange Sites sind keine _Forae_, das macht tden wesentlichen Unterschied!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Sicher nicht mit Deppen Leer Zeichen. Schon weil der Kunde König ist, und nicht Zwangsbeschulungter, wird im Restaurant sehr viel funktionieren, der Ton macht hier die Musik.

Comment: @Christian Geiselmann: Auch Dir vielen Dank für die ausführliche und sehr kreative Antwort, habe an mehreren Stellen schmunzeln müssen :) Das zweite Beispiel war übrigens nicht unbedingt für den Zweck des Kennenlernens gemeint, sondern z.B. wenn ich gesehen hätte, dass eine junge Frau ihre Mütze verloren hätte (die Situation ist mir sogar mal passiert und da habe ich sie mit "Entschuldigung" angesprochen).

Comment: @IgorO.  Für den Fall mit der Mütze wäre es natürlich am höflichsten, die Mütze aufzuheben, der Frau hinterherzuhechten, sie weitläufig zu überholen, ihr dann von schräg vorne entgegenzutreten und zu sagen: "Verzeihen Sie, Sie haben Ihre Mütze verloren." - Ansonsten, wenn's schneller gehen muss und das Rufen unumgänglich ist: Mir fällt nichts besseres ein als **"Hallo junge Frau! Ihre Mütze!"**

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Es ist zwar alles am Fließen, aber darf ich trotzdem spitzfindig darauf hinweisen, dass a) mehrere Forümer *Fora* sind (oder sollte *Forae* ein Witz sein?) und b) "ein eigenes Forum" ja nicht unbedingt heißen muss "ein Stackexchange-Forum". Etwas muffig füge ich noch hinzu, dass ich die Unterscheidung zwischen *Forum* und dem, was wir hier haben, für zu wortklauberisch halte. (Ich lasse mich aber belehren durch Information, was der so prominente Unterschied wäre.)

Comment: Wie ich es verstanden habe, legt Stackexchange Wert darauf, dass es darum geht, konkrete Fragen zu beantworten und nicht - wie es für Foren typisch ist - Themen (endlos) zu diskutieren.

Comment: @Rha  Ach so. Nun gut. Dann habe ich bisher vielleicht ein zu wenig präzises Forenbild gehabt. Ich dachte, Forum ist ein Platz im Internet, wo man Fragen stellen, auf Antwort hoffen oder Dinge auch kommentieren kann, unabhängig von der Präzision und Endgültigkeit der möglichen Antworten. Ich dachte immer die Stackex-Sites seien einfach besonders kultivierte Foren...

Comment: @Christian _Fora_ ist natürlich der korrekte Plural, ich war immer schon schlecht in Latein :-/ ...

Answer (score 5):

Wie gefragt und erklärt: Ein "höflicher Begriff für eine junge Frau" existiert für den gewünschten Verwendungszweck nicht (mehr).

Worum geht es hier? Wozu die explizite Erwähnung des Alters einer Frau?

> Wenn ich z.B. meinem Opa erzählen würde, dass es eine junge Frau gibt, die mir gefällt und es würde sich um eine junge Frau handeln, die z.B. 23 ist, welches Wort würde ich hier am besten nehmen?

Wenn Mann einfach dem Großvater mitteilen möchte, man habe eine nette Person kennengelernt, dann spielt das Alter keine Rolle. In so gut wie *keiner* Situation *kann* diese diminutivierende Zusatzkennzeichnung eine relevante und präzise Zusatzinformation liefern, die im Rahmen der Höflichhkeit bleiben kann. Höflichkeit heisst Rücksichtnahme. Auch auf verqueere Ansichten.

Heteronormatives, peripheres Paarungsanbahnungsverhalten, ausgedrückt in deutscher Sprache gegenüber der eigenen Familie?

Was offensichtlich mit der Betonung auf das Alter der Frau gesagt werden soll: "Ich habe eine potentiell passende Geschlechtspartnerin zu Fortpflanzungszwecken entdeckt, deren biologische Uhr eine hohe Fruchtbarkeit erwarten lässt?"

In diesem privaten Rahmen sind die Höflichkeitserwartungen reduzierter als das in der Öffentlichkeit der Fall wäre. Da man in diesem Fall sowieso schon sexistische Sprachmuster reproduziert haben wird, ist Fräulein mit einem Augenzwinkern wahrscheinlich die effektivste Methode mit dem Opa zu kommunizieren. Hat man Glück, ermahnt der Opa den Fragesteller dann und erklärt dem Paarungsbereiten, dass er dieses Wort zu diesem Zweck besser nicht in der Öffentlichkeit verwenden sollte, aber man sei ja unter sich.

> Wenn ich auf der Straße einer unbekannten jungen Frau hinterherrufen würde, damit sie stehen bleibt und auf mich wartet, wie würde ich sie in diesem Fall am besten ansprechen? Was würde ich in diesem Fall rufen?

Wieder die Frage: wozu sich auf das Alter beziehen?
Wurde ein Schlüsselbund verloren? Will der Fragesteller nach dem Weg fragen?

Dann ist Christian Geiselmanns Vorschlag, auch die aus seiner "Situation Opa", ein geeignetes Mittel auf sich und die besondere Situation de Kontaktaufnahme aufmerksam zu machen ("überhaupt keine Bezeichnung zu wählen.").
Eine geeignete Anrede zu finden ist nicht gerade einfach in solchen Fällen, und es ist trotz der kürzlichen Debatten (à la #metoo) absolut legitim fremde Frauen anzusprechen, egal aus welchem Grund.  Kontext und Ausführung sind dabei unverzichtbar. Auf das Alter der weiblichen Person in der Anrede einzugehen ist jedoch niemals *höflich.* Je nach Kontext kann das durchaus witzig gemeint sein, durchaus witzig "ankommen". Eben auch durch den Bruch mit Höflichkeitsregeln oder (ironisch?) demonstrativen Konservatismus.

Es kommt also auf den Grund an, warum "sie" anhalten soll. Ist man selbst durch und durch Sexist und sucht eine Frau zu Paarungszwecken, *"die auf sowas steht":* dann kann man durchaus auch "Junge Frau!" rufen. Und sich gewiss sein, dass alle umstehenden in Hörweite den zur Schau getragenen Sexismus auf je ihre Weise zu würdigen werden wissen.

---

Update: sources!

Da diese Sichtweise augenscheinlich auf die Kritik der Voter zu treffen scheint:

> [[…] spricht grundsätzlich jeden mit "Guten Morgen, junge Frau", "guten
>    Morgen, junger Mann" usw. an, und zwar jeden und immer. Das geht mir
>    mehr und mehr auf den Keks, […]](http://bfriends.brigitte.de/foren/wie-denken-sie-ueber-umgangsformen-/114313-anrede-junge-frau-liebes-kind-usw.html)
>
> ["Junger Mann" ist für mein Empfinden eben keine "neutrale" Anrede. "Jung" suggeriert Unerfahrenheit und stellt gleich, ob bewusst oder unbewusst, eine Hierarchie her. Ich stehe mitten im Leben und bekleide mehrere verantwortungsvolle Positionen. Mich anzureden wie einen Heranwachsenden (und nur für diese Altersgruppe halte ich die Anrede für angemessen) ist schlichtweg daneben! Und wenn man den Namen nicht "parat" hat, ist ein neutrales "Guten Tag" allemal besser als so eine unangemessene Floskel. Außerdem gibt es ja auch noch die Möglichkeit, beispielsweise am Buffet zu sagen: "Was kann ich für Sie tun, der Herr?" statt "Na junger Mann, was darf´s denn sein?" So wurde ich zuletzt mit 16 beim Einkaufen bei unserem Bäcker angesprochen! Vor allem, wenn die Leute in meinem Alter oder gar jünger sind, finde ich die Anrede schlichtweg unpassend und auch unhöflich!](https://www.xing.com/communities/posts/bis-zu-welchem-alter-ist-die-anrede-junger-mann-slash-junge-frau-noch-angemessen-1012448034)

Allgemeine Präzisionsprobleme:

> [Die Anrede "Junger Mann" macht mich rasend](http://www.tagesspiegel.de/berlin/fallstricke-des-alltags-die-anrede-junger-mann-macht-mich-rasend/9186342.html)

Knigge.de:

> [Anrede von Unbekannten](http://www.knigge.de/themen/kommunikation/anrede-von-unbekannten-4705.htm)
>   Beim Gemüsehändler, in der Bäckerei oder beim Gastronom werden Kunden oder Gäste gerne mal mit "junger Mann" oder "junge Frau - was kann ich für Sie tun?" angesprochen.
>
> Sie halten dies für unhöflich, unangemessen und fühlen sich geringschätzig behandelt?
>   Sicherlich, im Allgemeinen ist diese Anrede nett gemeint, wenn auch recht vertraulich. Aber lohnt es sich deshalb wirklich, darüber eine Diskussion anzufangen? Es ist kaum anzunehmen, dass Sie dann besser bedient werden.

Und aus der etwas weiblicheren bis feministischen Perspektive, eines von mehreren Beispielen dort:

> [Mädel, Dame, Fräulein, Frau, Lady, … ?](http://maedchenblog.blogsport.de/2010/05/11/maedel-dame-fraeulein-frau-lady/)
>
> Weder fühle ich mich von Frau, Fräulein, junge Dame, … beleidigt oder angegriffen. Es ist der Kontext, in dem diese Worte fallen, der eher angreifend wahrgenommen werden kann. Und selbst dann bilde ich mir keine ein („patriarchalische Systeme“), sondern schaue, wie mein Gegenüber mit diesen Worten umgeht.

Und im Kontext der genannten Beispiele aus der Frage sollte deutlich geworden sein, dass die gewünschte Zusatzkennzeichunng gerade selbst die möglichen Probleme in so einer Kommunikationsproblem erst heraufbeschwört oder verschärft.

Comment: Was bitte ist Sexismus, wenn man zu einer jungen Frau "junge Frau" sagt? Ein junger Mann, der "junger Mann" genannt wird, fühlt sich nicht beleidigt.

Comment: @tofro, Sexismus ist, in einer Situation von einer jungen Frau zu sprechen, in der man nicht von einem jungen Mann sprechen würde.

Comment: @CarstenS Verstanden. Ich werde in Zukunft zu allen jungen Frauen "junger Mann" sagen. Das scheint mir am unverfänglichsten. ;)

Comment: Sehr schöner Beitrag! - Kleine Anmerkung: Eine junge Frau mit "junge Frau" anzureden, halte ich für eine doch recht milde Form von Sexismus (v.a. gemessen an Dingen wie "Na, Süße?"). Aber gut... der Kontext macht die Musik...

Answer (score 2):

Es hängt vom Kontext ab.

Vorweg:

"Mädel" geht gar nicht, das ist leider auch politisch belastet.

---

"Frau" wird Frauen unter 18 etwas irritieren, ist aber prinzipiell korrekt (z.B im Berufsleben, oder wenn es sonstwie "amtlich" wird).

"Fräulein" ist veraltet, aber generell trotzdem aktzeptiert, wenn es nicht gerade abwertend gebraucht wird, wie z.B. im Zorn:

> Das machst Du kein zweites mal **Fräulein** !

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob im Englischen "Miss" (für unverheiratete junge Frau) ebenfalls veraltet ist (ich bin halt schon so alt ;-) ). "Mrs." ist (war) definitiv für verheiratete oder *gereifte* Frauen reserviert.

Mal andersrum gefragt: Wie würde man denn ein *Kind* unter 16 Jahren in einem amtlichen Anschreiben ansprechen?

Mit **Frau** macht man bestimmt nichts falsch, ausser die *jungen* Frauen daran zu gewöhnen, dass sie solche sind.

---

Du hast Deine Frage weiter ausgeführt:

> Wenn ich z.B. meinem Opa erzählen würde, dass es eine junge Frau gibt,
>   die mir gefällt und es würde sich um eine junge Frau handeln, die z.B.
>   23 ist, welches Wort würde ich hier am besten nehmen?

**Junge Frau** ist korrekt in diesem Kontext.

> Wenn ich auf der
>   Straße einer unbekannten jungen Frau hinterherrufen würde, damit sie
>   stehen bleibt und auf mich wartet, wie würde ich sie in diesem Fall am
>   besten ansprechen? Was würde ich in diesem Fall rufen?

**"Hallo, würden *Sie* bitte mal kurz stehen bleiben ..."**

Ist wohl am *höflichsten* und impliziert weder Geschlecht noch Alter (als nicht relevant).

Im Zweifel kann auch **Du** verwendet werden, wenn man ein Kind anspricht.

Comment: Ich vermute, Kinder bzw. Leute unter 16 werden in amtlichen Schreiben gar nicht direkt angesprochen, weil das Amt sich immer an den Vormund zu wenden hat.

Comment: *»"Mädel" geht gar nicht, das ist leider auch politisch belastet.«* - Inwiefern?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Nazi belastet. Z.b. "Bund  deutscher **Mädel**" Meine Mutter war Gruppenfüherin, ich mag den Scheiss nicht, Das Wort ist "verschmutzt"!

Comment: Also in Wien, und auch in der Steiermark, besteht diese Konnotation nicht. Ein Kind ist entweder ein Bub oder ein Mädel (oder Mäderl). Das Wort ist übrigens auf dieselbe Weise aus dem Wort *Maid* entstanden, wie *Mädchen*: Durch Anfügen eines Diminutivsuffixes. Nur sind eben im Süden die Suffixe *-el* und *-erl* verbreiteter als das eher aus dem Norden stammende *-chen*. Vielleicht kling im Norden bei *Mädel* auch deswegen das dritte Reich mit, weil dort dieses Wort nur in diesem Zusammenhang verwendet wurde, während es im Süden lange davor und auch jetzt noch ein Alltagswort ist.

Comment: @Hubert Ich kann einfach nicht anders: Die Scheiss Nazis haben es "kaputt gemacht". Da gibt's mehr so Beispiele. Die "Österreicher" haben es ja auch gut verstanden, sich nach 1945 von der "ganzen Sache" zu distanzieren, und machen uns ihre gloriose Distanz vor bis heute (nix perssönliches, sorry. Und ich liebe Österreich BTW, bin regelmässig dort).

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann: "Ich vermute, Kinder bzw. Leute unter 16 werden in amtlichen Schreiben gar nicht direkt angesprochen, weil das Amt sich immer an den Vormund zu wenden hat." - da liegst du falsch. Den ersten Brief, den meine Tochter wenige Tage nach ihrer Geburt bekommen hat (und der namentlich an sie adressiert war), begann mit "Sehr geehrte Frau <Familienname>" und enthielt ihre Steueridentifikationsnummer. Und auch sämtliche Bankpost in den darauffolgenden Jahren an sie folgte diesem Muster.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: Ich gebe dir vollkommen recht. Als ich in die Schule ging (Matura im Jahr 1983) gab es zwar schon den [Herrn Karl](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Der_Herr_Karl), aber im Unterricht waren noch immer die bösen Deutschen die Täter, und Österreich war das erste Opfer. Dabei saß bis 1986 ein ehemaliger SS-Oberstrumführer in unserem Parlament (Friedrich Peter, bis 1978 Parteichef der FPÖ). Österreich hat es meiner Meinung nach noch sehr viel nötiger, sich von den Nazis zu distanzieren als Deutschland. Aber das passiert hierzulande leider nicht. Und dafür hasse ich viele meiner Landsleute.

Comment: Aber trotzdem ist Politik bzw. Zeitgeschichte von der Sprache zu trennen. Kleine weibliche Kinder, bis ca. 10 Jahre werden in Österreich vor allem am Land »Mäderl« genannt. Da schwingt kein bisschen Politik oder sonstwas mit. Danach geht man überal dort, wo Dialekt gesprochen wird, zum Begriff »Dirndl« über, mit dem traditionell eine weibliche Person zwischen ca. 10 Jahren und der Eheschließung bezeichnet wird. »Dirndl« ist übrigens auch ein Diminutiv, nämlich von der »Dirn« (hochdeutsch: Dirne). Das war nichts anderes als die Bezeichnung für eine junge unverheiratete Frau von niederem Status.

Comment: Im gesamten Sprachraum kennt man den Begriff »Dirndl« als Bezeichnung für ein Kleid mit weitem Ausschnitt, das aus dem Alpenraum kommt. Eigentlich heißt dieses Kleid aber »Dirndlkeid« und war eigentlich das Festtagskleid einer Dirn oder eines Dirndls. Die *Dirn* in ihrer ursprünglichen Bedeutung hat sich übrigens noch im Kinderlied [Spannenlanger Hansl](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spannenlanger_Hansel) erhalten. Aber sowohl *Dirndl* als auch *Mädl* oder *Mäderl* sind in Österreich gängige Begriffe, mit denen weder eine sexuelle (Dirne) noch eine politische (Mädel) konnotation einhergeht.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Vielen Dank für die ausführliche Antwort! Leider habe ich nicht das gefunden, was ich gesucht habe, aber jetzt weiß ich zumindest sicher, dass ein solches Substantiv im Deutschen nicht existiert. Selbst auf Wikipedia wird keine deutsche Version für "Девушка" vorgeschlagen. Ich persönlich finde es schade, denn das Bedürfnis in den oben beschriebenen Fällen solche Umwege zu suchen deutet für mich klar auf eine Lücke in der Sprache hin. Umso mehr finde ich es schade, dass das Wort "Fräulein" nicht dafür gebraucht werden kann, denn es klingt so schön :).

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Die Nazis dürften ungefähr 95% unseres heutigen deutschen Wortschatzes im Sinne ihrer Ideologie verwendet haben. Wenn wir auf jedes Wort verzichten würden, dass in irgendeiner Form dort missbraucht wurde, stünden wir so ziemlich ohne Sprache da. Ich bin bei dir, dass Wortneuschöpfungen der Nazi-Zeit heute ein no-go sind, aber ein so harmloses Wort wie "Mädel" in die ideologische Büsserecke zu stellen, finde ich ziemlich übertrieben.

Comment: Mädel ist politisch überhaupt gar nicht vorbelastet. Bitte den Quatsch löschen.

Comment: @LangLangC Autsch. Der Volksstamm der Bayern als Nabe des Bösen.

Comment: @äüö   Nach meiner Wahrnehmung ruft die Verwendung des Wortes "Mädel" in Gebieten außerhalb des bayerisch-österreichischen Sprachraums durchaus NS-Assoziationen wach. Das ist ja auch logisch: Das Wort wurde dort einfach nicht verwendet außer eben genau in der Zeit der Hitlerdiktatur. Übrigens ist "Mädel" schon im Schwabenland schon nicht gebräuchlich. Da heißt es "Mädle", und wer immer "Mädel" sagte, würde damit auffallen, eben weil das Wort an 1933-1945 erinnert. Die benachbarten Bayern wiederum würden eher "Madel" sagen, also mit einfachem "a".

Comment: Hier in Mitteldeutschland ist Mädel ein ganz normales Wort wie Haus und Baum, und jeder verwendet das umgangssprachlich fürs weibliche Geschlecht. Ich bin sehr verwundert, was in anderen Gegenden so abgeht... Man sieht wieder gut, wie sich die deutsche Sprache in 40 Jahren in Ost und West schon stark auseinanderentwickelt hat.

Comment: äüö  Ich glaube, es ist gar nicht eine Ost-West-Teilung, sondern es sind einfach die Gepflogenheiten der verschiedenen Dialektnester, die seit Jahrhunderten bestehen.

Comment: @tofro Kein No-Go, aber man sollte sich des Makels bewusst sein und die ["LTI"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprache_des_Nationalsozialismus) keinesfalls gedankenlos verwenden, so dass ihre Entmenschlichung darin weiterleben könnte!

Comment: @HubertSchölnast "Ein Kind ist entweder ein Bub oder ein Mädel (oder Mäderl)." Und was ist mit Interkindern?

Answer (score 0):

Wie wäre es mit dem relativ neuen Begriff der "**Lady**"?

Ich persönlich finde die Bezeichnung furchtbar, aber scheint er heute in einigen Bevölkerungsgruppen bereits als Begriff für eine junge Frau rege Verwendung zu finden. Ohne negative Konnotation und rein positiv behaftet.

Ebenfalls kann man den Begriff immer häufiger im TV hören, wenn eine Gruppe von jungen Frauen als "Ladies" zusammengefasst wird. Vorrangig in Flirt-Shows wie dem Bachelor oder Take me out.

Comment: Es mag sein, dass das in populären Unterhaltungsmedienformaten propagiert wird. Persönlich fände ich Igors "Djevuschka" aber schöner. Außerdem hört, wer immer mal in russischsprachigen Gegenden war, dabei deutlich die Höflichkeit und Achtsamkeit mit, die dieser Anrede zueigen ist.